# Search for list of files by name across many drives simultaneously

Tags: windows-8

I have several drives mounted in windows:

```
E:\, F:\, G:\, H:\ I:\, J:\, K:\, etc...
```

I want to search for a list of file names across all of these drives in one step rather than selecting each drive and searching it.

```
dir *name1*,*name2*,*name3*,*name4* /S /B
```

Which would return a list of matches as they are discovered:

```
E:\folder\name4.txt
F:\documents\name1.txt
```

Problem is the find command only allows one name to search and one drive to search

```
DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N] ...
```